# What is the difference between "dotnet build xxx.sln" vs "dotnet build .proj" by .proj?

Tags: .net, jenkins, .net-core, nuget

It seems the two methods have some difference as if I try to build using my sln it throws all sorts of error (like cannot copy, part of path cannot found or complaining about possible path length limit) but if I build .proj by .proj (according to sln) it build fine ? It is happening inside Jenkins .net6 build container. It is failing during restore stage.

Any idea what it can be ?

Thanks

Comment: Simple: `sln` files are not MSBuild project files.

Comment: Right, but "dotnet build" is expecting a solution file or a project file, so it should work with both, but doesn't. 
dotnet build [<PROJECT>|<SOLUTION>]

It works with it but during implicit restore it has all sorts of problem...while doing the same 1by1 with .proj files all is good. And I would like to understand the reason.

Comment: Exactly what version of `dotnet` and `msbuild.exe` and location are you using? (Run `where msbuild` to get the path). And exactly what command-lines were you using? Are you using VS's Developer Command Prompt (from the start-menu shortcuts) or some other console/shell environment?

Comment: It is jenkins build agent running on openshift using sdk6 image (dotnet/sdk:6.0)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that  using `msbuild` or `dotnet` with an `.sln` file requires [the Visual Studio Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2022) to be available, which is Windows-only. I might be wrong though...